# What do we call the past movement to latinize English?

Tags: history

When examining intriguing etymologies, Merriam-Webster often brings up a historic movement to regularize the English language by making it more like Latin, as they do in [this video](https://youtu.be/n4PWP8uL-1o) examining the pluralization of *octopus*.

I know that this movement was at least prevalent in the eighteenth century, and I believe it started even earlier. I tried to research it, but all of my queries returned articles about the modern impact of Latino culture on English and a push to expel foreign language from usage in public American facilities, such as schools.

What is the name for this movement? How could I find more information on it?

<sub>*Please include additional tags if you feel they are appropriate.*</sub>

Comment: You mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform#Undoing_the_damage ?

Comment: @tchrist I believe so! The video I linked at least talks about a very similar practice: people used *octopi* even though *octopus* is not Latin in origin. Thank you for that link!

Comment: It was nothing like a "movement". It was some cranks who got some power in some places, who were predictably ineffectual and silly in their beliefs, and whose legacy, if any, is ignorance.

Comment: @JohnLawler That’s very juicy! I had no idea. It sounds like you could definitely provide some insightful information in the form of an answer.

Comment: You're talking about those responsible for the *p* in *receipt* to make it look more like *recepta*, right?

Comment: @KarlG To be honest, I’m not entirely sure. I’ve just heard it mentioned several times without much explanation. I believe the ‘movement’ would have been responsible for spelling change as well, but I don’t know for certain.

Comment: Given your example, it seems likely you're not talking about a movement so much as a facet or facets of what has been called the [Renaissance movement](https://prezi.com/z3ct4oynq2xl/history-of-greek-and-latin-influence-on-the-english-language/) (see the capsule summary for 1500-1650). Search for ["influence of latin and greek on english"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=influence+of+latin+and+greek+on+english&t=canonical&ia=web) for more detail.

Comment: David Crystal's book "[The Fight for English: How the Pundits Ate, Shot, and Left](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/the-fight-for-english-9780199207640?cc=gb&lang=en&)" covers this well.

Comment: I really don’t understand what you mean by “regularise the English language by making it more like Latin”. The _octopus_ example is a case of making English **less** regular and more confusing by imposing Latin inflection. Could you give some more examples of what development you’re talking about?

Answer (score -3):

Willam Shakespeare was famous for creating [neologisms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/neologism). Shakespeare [introduced](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/what-contributios-william-shakespeare-john-milton-371754) many Latin and Greek words into the English language as well as creating many new words.

Comment: "neologism" is not remotely what is being asked about. There was no "neologism" movement...